# What apps can not be created with flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am very interested about what apps I can not create using flutter?
It seems like almost everything (except what?) can be done, and the only price of cross-platform is app speed.

Comment: e.g. I found it quite difficult to build the following apps with flutter: games, background services, apps that need to use some api in Android/ios, but without corresponding packages in flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary downside of using Flutter is library support. Only a very small number of libraries have been ported over. For instance, Realm is a popular database solution. It has not been ported to Dart or Flutter. So if you have either an existing app or an idea for an app that you want to develop in Flutter, then you should first think about what libraries you need (databases, maps, etc.) and then ensure that there exist the appropriate libraries.

Everything CAN be done in Flutter, but unless all of the main libraries you need have been ported over, it will be a lot of work. So in that case, you should choose a different framework.

Comment: Worth noting too that even basic things like _notifications_ don't have proper, cross-platform support yet.